# Phrase or idiom for only having seen one part of something but not the whole thing?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For example, suppose I am a student studying physics, and I've taken a bunch of theoretical classes in electromagnetism, quantum mechanics, particle physics, etc. But I have not done any experimental physics, which some would argue is also integral to a physics education.

How can I complete a sentence along the lines of:

> Although I enjoyed learning the theory, I knew I was missing [not exactly sure what to put here, but I want to say that experimentation is like the "missing half" in my physics education].

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although I enjoyed learning the theory, I knew I hadn't seen **the
> whole picture**, because I lacked experimental courses.

**the whole picture** (idiom)

> The overall sense or presentation of a situation, concept, topic,
> etc., including all related factors and potential consequences. You're
> focusing on one small part of the negotiation, but you need to see the
> whole picture—we may need to compromise on a few items to get the best
> deal in the end. [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+whole+picture)

---

> The function of university research was initially relevant for W. von
> Humboldt, because the assumption was that only someone who occupies
> themselves on a daily basis in verifying theories and discovering new
> truths can **see the whole picture** in a particular field...
> [Aleksander Kobylarek; *The Polish Humboldtian University in the Face
> of Paradigmatic Change*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Polish_Humboldtian_University_in_the/eB5UDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22see%20the%20whole%20picture%22%20university&pg=PA215&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

You call somebody a "frog at the bottom of a well".

It is a famous Chineses idiom that is stated when somebody is making seemingly confident assumptions but from another's perspective they are just ignorant.

It is almost always used in a derogatory manner.

"You’re a frog at the bottom of a well" means you have a narrow viewpoint … that **you think the sky you can see out of the top of the well is all there is to the world**.

Used in your sentence you could say:

> Although I enjoyed learning the theory, I knew I was merely a frog at the bottom of a well.

[Frog of the well](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chinese_Stories/The_frog_of_the_well)

Comment: Interesting phrase, but it seems to mean the opposite of knowing you're missing something.

Comment: That is true, usually it is directed to the ignorant, not the educated, and rarely oneself. However, I feel like you are looking for a derogatory phrase, which this could substitute the purpose for.

Answer (score -1):

I have greatly enjoyed studying theoretical physics but experimentation is the lifeblood of science and I feel that without that I am really studying only half the subject.